# zend route exclude one string

Tags: zend-framework, routes, zend-route

I defined

```
routes.kategoriler.route               = ":lang/categories/:cat/:name"
routes.kategoriler.defaults.controller = "category"
routes.kategoriler.defaults.action     = "index"


routes.categories.route               = ":lang/:type/:cat/:name"
routes.categories.defaults.controller = "types"
routes.categories.defaults.action     = "index"
```

type catches "categories" word. I put definitions before and after but no way. Can you offer a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using hint from
[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

```
routes.categories.reqs.type_name        =  "^((?!categories).)*$"
```

Solved my case

Answer (score 2):

Use a requirement for type to do not match 'categories'. Like this:

```
routes.categories.reqs.type = "[^categories]"
```

Sadly my regex skills aren't on the top, so you might want to rewrite it (It's a little ugly, and it disapproves anything that contains 'categories', but it gives you the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to accept anything except the exact match of "categories" use the below regexp

```
^((?!^categories$).)*$
```

this will allow you to use the type as "my-categories" or "categories-of-products" or anything else that is not an exact match of "categories"